# Bad substitution error on Solaris for arguments 10 and above

Tags: shell, solaris, sh

I need to handle more than 10 parameters in script.
I was declaring and assigning after 9th parameter like below.

```
param10=${10}
param11=${11}
param12=${12}
```

It is working fine in linux, but not in solaris. I am getting `bad substitution`

Can any one help me to read paramters more than 10 and that should work for both solaris and linux.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe out of date, but according to [this link](ftp://service.boulder.ibm.com/ps/products/cmvc/doc/tr/tr292332.txt):

> The Bourne shell only supports positional parameters $0 through $9. 
>   In order to access parameters 10 or greater, you must use the "shift"
>   command.  Shift will move $2 to $1, $3 to $2, etc. ($0 is the name of
>   the command being invoked and never shifts). Also, you can shift more
>   than one position at a time.  For example, you can use $1 through $9,
>   then issue the command "shift 9" and process variables 10 through 19
>   using the variables $1 through $9 again.